# Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in (...) on line 4

Tags: php, mysql, function

Here is my snippet.

I've checked some other questions similar to my error, but so far I can't get it solved.

```
<?php 
function user_exists ($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username =  $username"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is because it is not returning any rows.

Comment: try to do an `echo` to see what does `sanitize($username)` return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split your code in some more lines to handle those errors or special cases. `mysql_query` will return zero to n rows or an error if it occurs. The returned *resource* will therefore only be true on non-error queries. This can be used to handle such situations like follows.

At first build and execute query, next process the *resource*.

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = ".$username;
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

u may use the following to determine what is going on in case of an error:

```
if(!$result) die("SELECT failed: ".mysql_error());
```

or these idea to handle the problem

```
if (!$result=mysql_query($query)) {
        return false; // or similar operation
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen, when `mysql_query` returns false, if it fails for some reason. So you should split this into multiple statements and check the return values

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username =  $username";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === false) {
    // error handling
    return false;
}

return (mysql_result($result, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

Comment: SORTED! I took out the single quotations from the field names. So instead of:
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SEL­ECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
I wrote ------->
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SEL­ECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;