# Need to display a MySQL table on a page using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-table

I'm trying to get a table to display and keep getting an error. Could someone out there with better coding skills help me?

Here is the code:

```
<?php 

// connect to the database

$host = "###";
$username = '###';
$pass = '###';

mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Employees") or die(mysql_error());

// select everything from the table

$query = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
$result = mysql_query($query') or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{
    echo "<td>".$row['employeeid']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['department']."</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

// disconnect from the database

mysql_close();
```

?>

---

When the page runs it yields the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/content/35/4683335/html/crosshill/display.php on line 36

Line 34 is:      `echo "<td>".$row['employeeid']."</td>";`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in (...) on line 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675232/warning-mysql-result-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource)

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: I don't think my hosting provider offers anything else. I'm just trying to do a simple assignment with the resources I have at my disposal. But I appreciate you point this out and when I change providers soon will use that feedback in selecting a new one.

Comment: If your provider uses a version of PHP that doesn't come with PDO, then run away, run far far away. They are using a version of PHP which is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you need check 3 points:

You could use `or die(mysql_error())` in dev environment to check if you have an error (with sql functions related).

1. Connection

   `mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass) or die(mysql_error());`
2. Select db

   `mysql_select_db("Employees") or die(mysql_error());`
3. Query (I see that you query are correct, but probably you table name are wrong, remember that names are case sensitive)

   `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Thanks very much! I've added those 3 check points and it passes all of them. I now get a different error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in ####/display.php on line 36

Comment: Line 33 is "echo "<td>".$row['employeeid']."</td>";" ( I changed the order to match the table, thinking that might be the problem. It did not help

Comment: the only thing removed is all the database info. Line 36 is the first attempt to print after the fetch array command. I'll update the code in the original question to reflect my edits. Thanks for the continued  help!

Comment: Just updated the original question to reflect changes to code. Thanks!

Comment: Now, you have a quote error in `$result = mysql_query($query') or die(mysql_error());` you sould have `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: You guys are all very great helps and good coders. I removed that and it went on to other errors. :) See above for other solutions. It is now working, but all item from that fetch_array request are on the same line. Any way to easily remedy that? And should I keep editing the question or start new ones in cases like this?

Comment: I think you should open a new question and paste here link, it's hard to remember all the steps of this question.

Comment: Thanks again. You've been very helpful and patient with me and I appreciate it. I'll open an new question for this last little tweak.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your database is called `Employees` as well as your table, is this a mistake or are they both the same name?

You also have syntax error here:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
$result = mysql_query($query') or die(mysql_error());
```

Remove the `'` so it is like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result)< 1){

   echo 'no rows founds';

} else {


echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

while( ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
{
    echo "<td>".$row['employeeid']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['department']."</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

}
```

**Side note:**
As suggested by others you should switch to either `mysqli_*` or perhaps `pdo`.

Comment: I did indeed. Thanks very much. It still has not solved it though, as now I am getting an "Access denied for user '###'@'%' to database 'Employees'. I'm pretty sure all credentials are in correct. Further ideas?

Comment: Firstly check the database is called Employees, notice also your table is also called Employees are you sure they are the same name?
Second check your user has the privileges to use that database (check cpanel for that). Cpanel > MySQL databases at the bottom look for `Add User To Database` and add that user to it with all the privalages.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! It was just the little mistake that I made of not using the database name (instead using the name of the table) Just like you pointed out. Greatly appreciate the patience and help! It's working now!

Comment: @WJB if the problem is solved please press the tick icon to the left of my answer :)!

Comment: As soon as my reputation allows I will be coming back and adding points for all of you helpful people. Really appreciate the patience with an obvious new user. :)

Comment: @WJB you just click the tick and up arrow next to my answer, your rep count does not stop you doing that.